# Typescript random number generation problem

Tags: javascript, random

This is driving me crazy as I can't see why this doesn't work!
The requirement is simple: Robot should have a new unique name after its name is reset (by calling `resetName()`). My logic is to continuously generate a new name and the uniqueness is enforced by a `Set`. But it doesn't work, namely, if I create a Robot instance, after calling `resetName` 10000 times, then there should have been 10001 unique names. But it doesn't; only around 9920 names, give or take as it's random, have been generated indicated by the `_counter` variable. Can't figure out why.

```
export class Robot {
  private capitals = [...Array(26).keys()].map(i => String.fromCharCode(i + 65)); // generate 26 capital letters.
  private _name = '';
  private static _seen = new Set<string>();
  private _counter: number = 0;
  constructor() {}

    // name is in the format of XXYYY where X is a captial letter and Y is a digit.
  public get name(): string {
    if (!this._name) {
      // continuously generate a new unique name.
      while (!Robot._seen.has(this._name)) {
        this._name = this.capitals[this.randomNumber(25)] + this.capitals[this.randomNumber(25)] + this.randomNumber(9) + this.randomNumber(9) + this.randomNumber(9);
        if (!Robot._seen.has(this._name)) {
          this._counter += 1;
          Robot._seen.add(this._name);
          break;
        } 
      }
    }
    
    return this._name;
  }

  public resetName(): void {
    this._name = '';
  }

  public static releaseNames(): void {
    //Robot._seen.clear();
  }
  
  // generate a random number between min and max inclusively.
  private randomNumber = (max: number, min: number = 0): number => Math.floor(Math.random()*(max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

This is the unit test that failed:

```
it('should set a unique name after reset', () => {
    const NUMBER_OF_ROBOTS = 10000
    const usedNames = new Set()

    usedNames.add(robot.name)
    for (let i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ROBOTS; i++) {
      robot.resetName()
      usedNames.add(robot.name)
    }

    expect(usedNames.size).toEqual(NUMBER_OF_ROBOTS + 1)
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your initial `while` condition is incorrect. If you were going to do this with a `while` loop, the condition should be:

```
while (!this._name || Robot._seen.has(this._name)) {
```

not

```
while (!Robot._seen.has(this._name)) {
```

You need to keep looping while the previously-seen set **does** have the new name, not while it *doesn't*.

But that logic can be markedly simplified:

```
public get name(): string {
    if (!this._name) {
        // continuously generate a new unique name.
        let name;
        do {
            name = this.capitals[this.randomNumber(25)] + this.capitals[this.randomNumber(25)] + this.randomNumber(9) + this.randomNumber(9) + this.randomNumber(9);
        } while (Robot._seen.has(name));
        Robot._seen.add(name);
        ++this._counter;
        this._name = name;
    }
    
    return this._name;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgpgHgDg9gTgFxMABAYwDYEMDOOUBKMARjAigN4BQKKUcAlgG5YJjpZQMJYb4C8KANoA6MQEE4cLAE8AFACYAbAEoRAazAycclQF0RAW05yGKfgD4UAZQSMAdgHMRAMzgxDAYQAWWOJ5gAEzBTFABqFCUAVhUVAG4UYFRHMHswaTYUZQ4uHgwUDDAENjgcERo6RhZMgH17LEN2QQByZriK+mZWdhweBAY0FBqcMFTzFDSAdxsigB5eh0cLXXbaTur2GrQYAFd7EoAuCZ3DYnTxgAZV9Bh7BZ20BHhdSgBfKgqkiYb2BnwGewoBDedgueDGcgwFwoAAaMIAmoiUJMQXB2DCUH8UFgcv1eAUiiVsfZAih4Zj8DjAgxHNxymsdsQMAMUClyPVGrojgsAY5KBVaAxoXIAITAv4iOo-FT82hyxKobb7AE7XY4DAyVmpdLdbETMDTPYMACOO3YHLA9PlBPZP2u8sCMFl1toFvG4rKaE43F4OCEHpE0hJHgAcicznBFDE9OEgd4JV7cr7-fGykHHYYw6d0lH9LGA+nQ+GcwBOGURAtYYOZ4uRsv51OBqsZrMRuRl+1y17I+OFFByIikBCSkapES+HQW2Kd2iDsgj0b2ERYQKBORTmfhMIBra7fbpTc7t2CC2d97ygUoNEIHZwQFHu0Vd4dRnMwZokYIEM-LkoJgwBhSWoeUH0acZWmuZ8GSZFlelYFk0UKXAwG-RodBUI5-0A51aCSOdh2GRcREwMA-BWJ8Kk+ZJtQydgcULQxjmzOAUDOBBJkXFBDABYlSWMCBMXsTAdhwZgwA1K11l1BjW3OQQ5H4o57FrAAaLiASU2tLgwpiI3MKwAFlWG8VwMBgZ4jOBJtq10EAFKwASAFp1MBCIAEZyxc+IPloNFYEQF5gLlJUcBgQoRDMxw5AAA0IsdRIALyaFAABIKHwhd4oYJLXjU7Y9iJQQ0p3fL9zgV5ou82h3mfELyHcIdximQgSDIciwRYuRCnIMxBCuTEUFmFA3IuUb+rCMIGBlILfNa4cPyKVCQiquUGvnU8qHeNb5rAfyEBWIA)

Notice that I kept `name` local until we knew it was unique. You *could* just write to `this._name` if you wanted:

```
public get name(): string {
    if (!this._name) {
        // continuously generate a new unique name.
        do {
            this._name = this.capitals[this.randomNumber(25)] + this.capitals[this.randomNumber(25)] + this.randomNumber(9) + this.randomNumber(9) + this.randomNumber(9);
        } while (Robot._seen.has(this._name));
        Robot._seen.add(this._name);
        ++this._counter;
    }
    
    return this._name;
}
```

...but I prefer not to commit changes like that to an object until I know they're correct. [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgpgHgDg9gTgFxMABAYwDYEMDOOUBKMARjAigN4BQKKUcAlgG5YJjpZQMJYb4C8KANoA6MQEE4cLAE8AFACYAbAEoRAazAycclQF0RAW05yGKfgD4UAZQSMAdgHMRAMzgxDAYQAWWOJ5gAEzBTFABqFCUAVhUVAG4UYFRHMHswaTYUZQ4uHgwUDDAENjgcERo6RhZMgH17LEN2QQByZriK%20mZWdhweBAY0FBqcMFTzFDSAdxsigB5eh0cLXXbaTur2GrQYAFd7EoAuCZ3DYnTxgAZV9Bh7BZ20BHhdSgBfKgqkiYb2BnwGewoBDedgueDGcgwFwoAAaMIAmoiUJMQXB2DCUH8UFgcv1eAUiiVsfZAih4Zj8DjAgxHNxymsdsQMAMUClyPVGrojgsAY5KBVaAxoXIAITAv4iOo-FT82hyxKobb7AE7XY4DAyVmpdLdbETMDTPYMACOO3YHLA9PlKECMFl1to4rKUsa4ydIjQnG4vBwQnd0hJHgAcicznBFDE9OEgd4JZ7cj6-bGygHbYYQ6d0hH9NH-VhA%20nQ1mAJwyiJ5gsZsNyUu55MiVPBovh0vXeWvZGxwooOREUgISUjVIiXw6d0usCxNtyvtkQejewiLCBQJyccW%20ICuVhMLj7Z7ErT97yrdohA7OCA9c-a7vDqM5mDNEjBBBn5clBMGAMUnUeXX10WjaCo7wZJkWV6VgWTRQpcDAN9Gh0FQji-H97VoJJZwHYYFw9WDw03WhjxQT5km1DJ2BxRtDGOTM4BQM4EEmBcUEMAFiVJYwIExexMB2HBmDADUrXWXVqKrc5BDkLijnsZsABpWIBWTm0uZDaLDcwrAAWVYbxXAwGBnl04EG3zNNdBAaSsG4gBaJTAQiABGMsHM3Co0VgRAXj-OUlRwGBChEQzHDkAADHDhwEgAvJoUAAEgoLD5yihhYteRT932SSEooPddmyuBXjCwiUHeO9-PIdx%203GKZCBIMgVioMF6LkQpyDMQQrkxFBZhQJyLkG7qdwYGVfNoaq52fIoEJCUqJoagcLXad5JoHTz4AQFYgA)

Comment: I knew it was something simple and I got really annoyed when I couldn't see it.

Comment: @stt106 - Yeah, and not just you, it took me longer than you might expect as well. Granted, I hadn't had my coffee yet... :-D